# Pointless grammar-only edits on questions

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits

I just started to look at the edit moderation queue and noticed a pattern in some of the edits. You would see the original as such:

---

i have a db that returns a query and i cant seem to get it to work.i do something like this:

```
string result = GetParseValue();
// some more code
var col = GetMyCollection(result);
```

---

and then comes the review:

---

I have a database that returns a query and I can't seem to get it to work. I do something like this:

```
string result = GetParseValue();
// Some more code
var col = GetMyCollection(result);
```

---

See, it is just about capitalizing letters, expanding an acronym, adding a missing apostrophe, and spacing after a period.

I usually reject that edit as it does not bring any value to the post. Even more when it does not involve any indentation. Also, it happens that it is done over many posts by the same user(s). Seems to me like an attempt to grab some easy reputation.

I don't mind the easy reputation, my concern is more about the fact that out of 30 queued posts, probably at least 10 of them were just this kind of edit from the same user.

How should this be dealt with? Should I keep rejecting or should they be considered an improvement? Should the user be told that the edit is too minor?

P.S.: The irony would be to get this post to be edited... (done, <s>though not actually for grammar</s>).

Comment: "Reject & Edit" is good option in this case.

Comment: Side note: I'm not sure what you call "abusive edit" as edit seem to be ok (if it would be done by 2K+ user and not require review).

Comment: WHY is this pointless??  I swear, every time I see a lower-case "i" that isn't a part of a variable name, I die inside.

Comment: It does bring value and should be fixed, but not by a sub-2k user.

Comment: You are 100% wrong here. Grammar fixes are undoubtedly an improvement—they make the post *easier to read*. They also make it look professional, an important goal on a site like this. Arguments like *"it is just about cap letters and spacing after a dot"* call the whole foundation of a language and an organized grammar into question. There is a reason it exists, so that you can be universally understood. The suggesters gain a token number of reputation for each approved edit, ultimately capped at 1k or 2k (I forget which). It is hardly worth worrying about.

Comment: @CodyGray In that case, why does StackOverflow try so hard to prevent people making grammatical changes, like the requirement for minimum number of characters difference etc.?

Answer (score 10):

It is more of the *amount* of the grammatical errors which a user is editing rather than the *grammar editing itself*, I think.

As long as the user edits significantly, be it grammar or format or tagging, then it should be accepted.

On the contrary, if a user gives little edit to the grammar, format, or tag, either because

1. The post itself in the first place has little grammatical error or having not-so-bad format or using already significant tags (only omitting minor tags), or
2. The user does small little changes on grammar/formatting or adding/removing non-significant but non-misleading tags - although there are many errors in the post.

Then I think you should reject it due to "no improvement whatsoever". And you could just choose reject & edit to edit it by yourself if you want.

Nevertheless, *don't* take it personally. Even when such edit comes from the same user, please judge it purely based on the edit he made. If you think that the edit is bad, then reject it. And if you think that the edit is good, then accept it.

If the same user keeps suggesting bad edits, then eventually his editing privilege will be suspended temporarily by the system. But who knows that he will learn a lesson from it and have better editing next time?

So, don't take it personally. Just review the suggested edit fairly.

Comment: Am I a bad person for wanting to change "personal" to "personal*ly*"?

Comment: @JamesQMurphy nope, I don't take it personally. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 4):

If the grammar is most that should be corrected, and there isn't something glaringly obviously more important to fix left, that's actually a good edit.

Now if the suggester just fixed the grammar of something which has to be completely rewritten, or should be removed, *that* would be a reason to reject (and probably do it yourself, if you can spare the time).

Admittedly, grammar-only edits are often not that important, still, it's nice for the posts to look somewhat professional and not make you stumble when reading.

Anyway, for this specific post, if it was all of it, that's something of a moot point:
It should be closed and downvoted, which would lead to it being cleaned away in short order, the same happening to the reputation gained.

Comment: Can't decide whether to upvote or downvote this. I agree with most of the answer, except for the part that suggests grammar-only edits are not that important. That is totally wrong—grammar can make or break a post, independent of content. There is absolutely no reason why you should hesitate to submit or improve a grammar-related edit.

Answer (score -6):

The capital letters are important. So for me it's an important edit.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing, it's just that this as an *answer* doesn't add any more substance than [my comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317835/pointless-grammar-only-edits-on-questions#comment314550_317835) above.